# Distribution of Top Speeds of Football (Soccer) Players

Tags: football

Is there any data on soccer player running speed distribution for any of the top leagues? It's relatively easy to find that the fastest players can reach top speeds around 37km/h, but what about average players, or by position?

Are there some standardised tests that players do, for example speed at 100m dash or any similar test?

Comment: Presumably wingers and full backs are the fastest. Kyle Walker,  Marcus Rashford, Phil Foden, Ryan Giggs, Theo Walcott are a few that spring to mind.  [This page](https://www.premierleague.com/news/3545885#:~:text=At%20the%20age%20of%2033,Brennan%20Johnson%20and%20Mykhailo%20Mudryk.) may be helpful.